# CORS Configuration not working in WSO2 API Manager for Oauth2/token API

Tags: cors, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API Manager version 4.1.0. In this, CORS configuration is not working even though all the configurations were made.

Note : I am not using WSO2 Identity server , only using API Manager.

I made the below configurations,

Deployment.toml file :

```
[apim.cors]
enable = true
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = "*"
allow_credentials = false
```

under the path "/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api" in *OpenService*.xml made the below changes as I couldnt find TokenAPI.xml only *OpenService*.xml were there in this version,

```
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
    <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
</handler>
```

Even after making these changes , facing below error,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://11.22.333.44:9443/oauth2/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Can someone help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth2-related endpoints configurations are packed in the `oauth2` web app located at the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2` folder. You need to enable the `CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter` from Apache CXF to handle CORS for the OAuth2-related endpoints through the spring beans configuration.

To enable CORS, add the following to the `cxf-servlet.xml` file located at `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2/WEB-INF` folder,

1. Add a new bean. Change the `allowOrigins` value according to your requirement.

```xml
<bean id="cors-filter" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.cors.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter">
    <property name="allowHeaders">
        <list>
            <value>Authorization</value>
            <value>X-WSO2-Tenant</value>
            <value>content-type</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="exposeHeaders">
        <list>
            <value>Content-Disposition</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="allowCredentials" value="true" />
    <property name="allowOrigins"
                value="http://localhost:3000"/>
</bean>
```

You can use a system property as well for the allowed Origins as follows,

```xml
<property name="allowOrigins"
        value="#{systemProperties['oauth.endpoints.allowed.origins'] != null ?
            systemProperties['oauth.endpoints.allowed.origins'].split(',') : {}}"/>
```

Then start APIM by passing the system properties,

```
sh bin/api-manager.sh -Doauth.endpoints.allowed.origins=http://localhost:3000
```

2. Register the bean under `jaxrs:providers`

```xml
<jaxrs:providers>
    <bean class="org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.expmapper.InvalidRequestExceptionMapper"/>
    <ref bean="cors-filter" />
</jaxrs:providers>
```

Comment: Hi @sanoj, Thank you so much it works.

 Still I have one more doubt. How to allow all the IPs and all the headers instead of specifying it.

 I tried using "<star_symbol>" in value like , **<property name="allowOrigins" value="<star_symbol>"/>**. 

Do u have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the CORS config globally, please check whether you have enabled it on the API level too.

Refer to https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/advanced-topics/enabling-cors-for-apis/#enabling-cors-per-api